# Manpage typography and proper dashes

Tags: man, unicode

Should manpages avoid using unicode characters like the m-dash (—)?
I've noticed most manpages use hyphens/minuses in their taglines where, I believe, an actual dash would have been more correct typographically.
The man-page of the dash shell lives up to its name and uses a proper m-dash.

I've filed a tentative pull request at https://github.com/rtomayko/ronn/pull/94 that fixes (?) this in `ronn`.

Opinions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix man pages (using the man macros) used a single hyphen in the NAME section to separate the name from the description.

```
.SH NAME
sh \- command language
```

Unix documents and papers often used an em dash (`\(em` in troff) where appropriate.

More recent man pages are based on the [mdoc](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mdoc.samples) macros, and use an `.Nd` macro to output an em dash. For instance, dash's man page includes

```
.Sh NAME
.Nm dash
.Nd command interpreter (shell)
```

and the definition of `.Nd` is

```
.de Nd
.nop \[em] \$*
..
```

It's probably best to use either `\(em` or the `.Nd` macro, but you'd probably be OK using a UTF-8-encoded em dash instead.